# Get Absolute Path Relative to DLL location

Tags: c#, dll, path

I have a dll that depends on some external files.
I have relative paths (relative to the dll location) to those files.

I need to be able to load/read those files from the DLL.

To find the absolute path to the files I was using:

```
System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(filePath);
```

It seemed to be working, but I found that this is actually returning a path relative to the 'current directory'.  I found that the current directory changes at some point from the dll location (and may never even be the dll path).

What's the easiest way to get the absolute path of the files relative to the DLL from code running in the DLL?

I was going to use the following, but found that it returns the path to the EXE that has loaded the DLL, not the DLL path:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

Comment: I think you can get the file name from the codebase: `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase` (if called inside a function in the dll ofcourse)

Comment: Yes.  That worked for me.  At least it finds the full path to the DLL (with file:/// preappended to the string).  Enter it as the answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Note that `GetFullPath` computes absolute path based on *current* directory, which may or may not happen to be the same as EXE location and can also change during application runtime.

Comment: This question could be duplicate of something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22661912/wpf-load-image-from-folder ... DLLs are generally don't bring additional files with themselves during deployment - so it may be better to actually make path relative to app..

Comment: In my case the DLL is a plugin to another app.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`GetFullPath` always assumes relative to the current directory unless you specify an absolute path.  You should just manually combine your assembly path with your relative path.  You can then normalize the result to get a clean path.

```
string assemblyPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
string filePathRelativeToAssembly = Path.Combine(assemblyPath, @"..\SomeFolder\SomeRelativeFile.txt");
string normalizedPath = Path.GetFullPath(filePathRelativeToAssembly);
```

For example.  If the assembly location is "C:\Test\MyAssembly.dll" then you get this

```
assemblyPath = "C:\Test"
filePathRelativeToAssembly = "C:\Test\..\SomeFolder\SomeRelativeFile.txt"
normalizedPath = "C:\Test\SomeFolder\SomeRelativeFile.txt"
```

Also, if you passed in an absolute path as the second part of `Path.Combine` it will still do the proper thing.

```
string assemblyPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
string filePathRelativeToAssembly = Path.Combine(assemblyPath, @"C:\AbsoluteFile.txt");
string normalizedPath = Path.GetFullPath(filePathRelativeToAssembly);
```

will give you

```
filePathRelativeToAssembly = "C:\AbsoluteFile.txt"
normalizedPath = "C:\AbsoluteFile.txt"
```

Comment: Great.  Thanks.  I ended up using something similar to what you proposed.

Answer (score 1):

To get the full path of the dll codebase, you can use this code:

```
string codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
```

You can further clean this path by using a uriBuilder:

```
UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
string cleanFullPath = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
```

Comment: The question was "What's the easiest way to get the absolute path of the files relative to the DLL from code running in the DLL?" so I'm not sure this is exactly what was requested.  May need some clarification from George.